# How do i remove a signal handler

Tags: c, posix, signal-handling

I've made the follow signal handler

```
struct sigaction pipeIn;
pipeIn.sa_handler = updateServer;
sigemptyset(&pipeIn.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &pipeIn, NULL) == -1){

    printf("We have a problem, sigaction is not working.\n");
    perror("\n");
    exit(1);    

}
```

How do I remove or block this particular handler so that I can set up another signal handler that uses the same signal? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `SIG_DFL` in place of the function pointer when calling [`sigaction(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

Comment: or just replace the existing signal handler with your new one; no need to remove the old one first.

Comment: if you just want to remove the signal handler (I found an example where I was getting circular signals) then `signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_DFL);` is equivalent without the awkwardness of the struct sigaction.